# How can I pass a list of html element as parameter into a Closure template

Tags: javascript, html, google-closure-templates

My template is this one below, and I'd like to use a list of html as parameter

```
{template .myTemplate}
    {@param title: string}
    {@param? listHtml: list<html>}
     <ul>
     {foreach $item in $listHtml}
       <li>
         <a>{$item}</a>
       </li>
     {/foreach}
    </ul>
{/template}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to pass a list of html elements as parameter when I call the template.

```
{call desktop.common.myTemplate }
     {param title: 'Contact us' /}
     {param listHtml kind="html" }
                          ????  
     {/param}
{/call}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about breaking out a helper template:

```
{template .myTemplate}
  {@param title: string}
  {@param? items: html}
  <ul>
    {$items}
  </ul>
{/template}

{template .myItemTemplate}
  {@param content: html}
  <li>
    <a>{$content}</a>
  </li>
{/template}
```

Which pushes iteration to the caller, where I assume the list of items is static:

```
{call desktop.common.myTemplate }
  {param title: 'Contact us' /}
  {param items kind="html"}
    {call desktop.common.myItemTemplate}
      {param content kind="html"}foo{/param}
    {/call}
    {call desktop.common.myItemTemplate}
      {param content kind="html"}bar{/param}
    {/call}
  {/param}
{/call}
```